# Wifi is disabled after a time of being unused

Tags: networking, wireless

I have this problem occasionally on Ubuntu 20.04. After a period of not using the computer, I get 'unable to load - check spelling' response from internet pages (or something similar).  It turns out that the wifi icon in the upper right has a question mark.

It seems to resolve if I manually turn off the wifi and then turn it back on.  I already have the 'connect automatically' setting turned on.  This is the only wifi defined for this computer.  The wifi is built-in to the computer.  The router is only about three feet from this computer.  What to do to be more consistent?

I do not think it is a wifi problem because I have another computer nearby that does not have problems (though this is Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on a different web site.  Kudos to MC.Naveen for this solution. (I do not know the protocol for referring away from this site to a competitor, so I provided attribution the best I could)

> Open terminal and run the following command
>
> ```
> sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix
> ```
>
> After entering the the Password, It will open the nano editor.
> Now Paste the Below Code
>
> ```
> !/bin/sh
> set -e
> if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
>      case "$1" in
>              pre) true ;;
>              post) sleep 1 && service network-manager restart ;;
>        esac
> fi
> ```
>
> Press Ctrl+O and Enter to save it.
>
> Press Ctrl+X to close the file.
>
> Now, make this a executable using this command.
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix
> ```
>
> That's it.